# Overlapping dates with fares

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT  price.car_number1, car_from, car_to, car_fares
FROM    price, car
WHERE   car.car_number1 = price.car_number1
```

The output looks like this:

```
car_number1    car_from     car_date      car_fare
------------------------------------------------------
BAL2018        2013-01-21   2013-01-26    $555         
BAL2018        2013-01-27   2013-01-28    $111
BAL2019        2013-01-26   2013-01-27    $211 
BAL2020        2013-01-26   2013-01-27    $545
```

Now suppose use want at UI result of rates from `2013-01-21` to `2013-01-28`, I want to some or other way to print the price of each car for their respective date and incase if the car do not have fares assigned it should display as `N/A`.

Please let me know if by anyway I can do this in mysql or anything with PHP

I want to make it look this (as in example)

```
           01-21   01-22 01-23 01-24 01-25  01-26 01-27 01-28 
 BAL2018   $555    $555  $555  $555  $555   $555  $111  $111
 BAL2019   N/A     N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A    $211  $211  N/A
```

Comment: Are bikes and cars the same thing?

Comment: Hi Strawberry, yes its same thing, it was typo error as bike :)

Comment: Hi halfer, it was typo error as bike, it is car, or u can consider it as vehicle incase confusion with bike n car :)

Comment: Do you want to show cars that don't have a price? If so, you'll need to change your `WHERE` join to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: OK. And, for clarity, please provide the expected result.

Comment: You can use `CASE` to conditionally put 'N/A' in the fare column if it does not apply - see the MySQL manual for syntax.

Comment: Hi Halfer and strwberry, just added the thing what exactly is required!! :)

Comment: You can 1) create a stored procedure or better… 2) make PHP handle the missing dates.

Comment: What happens if someone chooses `2013-01-23` - `2013-01-25`? Which rows should display?

Comment: Hi Salman, it shud give the respective car number fare and if its not in the list (it shud display N/A) AND as long as the car it has to display for at-least 1 day in the given range, i.e. it will not display and car incase it doesnt have the fare entered for the entered range of dates

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing without the actual data to work with, but something like this?

```
SELECT  car.car_number1, car.car_from, car.car_to, 
            ifnull(price.car_fares,'N/A') as car_fare
FROM    car left join price ON car.car_number1=price.car_number1
WHERE   car.car_from >= '2013-01-21' and car.car_to < '2013-01-28'
```

I'm assuming that the `car_fares` field is in the `price` table, and all other fields are in the `car` table.

Comment: No Gareth, with this query also getting above o/p only which is in question. Actually what I want to have is for particular date what is the fare and incase there is not fare assigned that day, it should display as N/A

Answer (score 0):

The best compromise, IMHO, would be to select the date range in MySQL and then
supply any missing info with PHP.

Pardon me for being possibly over-fussy, but one time or another I got bitten by all the problems below, so I'll give an apparently complicated solution to an apparently simple problem :-)

One problem may possibly arise from date selection algorithm, since "the next day"
is not so clear-cut an expression as one might think - some days are 23 hours or
25 hours long, when switching daylight saving time, and some days have one extra
second, so that $ts += 86400 takes you from D:M:Y 00:00:00 to D:M:Y 23:59:59 and
not to D+1:M:Y 00:00:00.

That can seem nit-picking until you lose fifteen hotel room reservations in July (or was it June?) because of a [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). It wasn't my code, but I was the one that had to do the mop-up.

Another problem would be that if you have a CAR_FROM of "1st January" and a CAR_TO
of "December 31st", and you wanted prices between 21 and 28 of March, then that row
would be relevant, even if no row specifies dates in March. So you need to take care of overlaps.

Finally, you might have an entry from 1-1-2013 to 31-12-2013, and later on you might have an entry for 1st May 2013 to 17th May 2013, and you would want the second one to take precedence for dates in the 1-17 May range. Actually you'd want a way of quickly selecting from one precedence system to another if the customer changes its mind.

So you might do it like this:

```
<?php

    $start = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month1, $day1, $year1);
    $stop  = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month2, $day2, $year2);

    $DATE_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y'; // This might be a define, actually

    // Use these dates in MySQL query. This takes care
// of most date problems.

    $SQL_From = date('Ymd000000', $start);
    $SQL_To   = date('Ymd235959', $stop);

    // We create a date array initialized with N/A, and use
    // a date format as a key
$empty = array();
    for ($ts = $start; $ts <= $stop; $ts += 86400)
    {
        $date = date($DATE_FORMAT, $ts);
        $empty[$date] = 'N/A';
    }

/*
To select dates overlapping [FROM-TO], consider that we do NOT want
a date when its TO is less than our FROM of interest:
    [from -- car -- to]   [FROM     TO]
and neither when its from is more than our TO of interest:
    [FROM     TO] [from -- car -- to]  
So we want all dates except those, and this means
    WHERE NOT ( car_to < SQL_From OR car_from > SQL_To)

But since NOT (A OR B) is logically equal to A AND B, we get this
not very intuitive, but very efficient query

    $query = ...
SELECT  price.car_number1, car_from, car_to, car_fares
FROM    price JOIN car ON car.car_number1 = price.car_number1
WHERE   car_from < $SQL_To AND car_to > $SQL_From
ORDER BY car_number1, car_from;

    The precedence is given by car_from: later dates win over earlier dates.
    But you might have a PRIORITY field that overrides all, so that PRIORITY=0
    means normal and PRIORITY 99 means "THESE are the prices, damn your eyes!";
    to achieve that, you can now simply "ORDER BY car_number1,priority,car_from."

*/

$cars = array();

// Now we retrieve all car data, with PDO or whatever

while($tuple = SQLFetchRow(...))
{
    // If this is a new car, we initialize its array to all N/A

    if (!isset($cars[$tuple['car_number1']))
        $prices = $empty;
    else
        $prices = $cars[$tuple['car_number1'];

    // Now we check our tuple and see what prices have changed
    // MySQL retrieves date in Y-M-D format

    list($y,$m,$d)  = explode('-', $tuple['car_from']);
    $from       = mktime(12, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
    list($y,$m,$d)  = explode('-', $tuple['car_to']);
    $to     = mktime(12, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);

    // This will overwrite any existing data with fresher data
        for ($ts = $from; $ts <= $to; $ts += 86400)
        {
            $date = date($DATE_FORMAT, $ts);
            $prices[$date] = $tuple['car_fare'];
        }

    // Now we save the modified array into $cars.
    $cars[$tuple['car_number1'] = $prices;
}

// And finally we print the results into a variable,
    // so it will be easier to wrap this into a helper function.

$row = '<tr>';
$row .= '<th>-</th>';
foreach($empty as $date => $dummy)
    $row = '<th>'.$date.'</th>';
$row .= '</tr>';

$table  = '<table>' . $row;

foreach($cars as $plate => $prices)
{
    $row = '<tr><td>'.$plate.'</td>';
    foreach($prices as $dummy_date => $price)
        $row .= '<td>'.$price.'</td>';
    $row .= '</tr>';

    $table .= $row;
}
$table  .= '</table>';

print $table;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below `calendar` is a simple utility table holding all dates that could ever be required. Personally, I'd most likely handle the missing values and, certainly, the pivoting at the application level, for ease of scalability.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fares;

CREATE TABLE fares
( vehicle_id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL 
, fare_start DATE NOT NULL
, fare_end DATE NULL
, fare DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL 
, PRIMARY KEY(vehicle_id,fare_start)
);

INSERT INTO fares VALUES 
('BAL2018','2013-01-21','2013-01-26',555.00),
('BAL2018','2013-01-27','2013-01-28',111.00),
('BAL2019','2013-01-26','2013-01-27',211.00), 
('BAL2020','2013-01-26','2013-01-27',545.00);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehicles;

CREATE TABLE vehicles
(vehicle_id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,description VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES 
('BAL2018','vehicle01'),
('BAL2019','vehicle02'),
('BAL2020','vehicle03');

SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE dt BETWEEN '2013-01-20' AND '2013-01-28';
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2013-01-20 |
| 2013-01-21 |
| 2013-01-22 |
| 2013-01-23 |
| 2013-01-24 |
| 2013-01-25 |
| 2013-01-26 |
| 2013-01-27 |
| 2013-01-28 |
+------------+

 SELECT c.dt,v.vehicle_id,f.fare_start,f.fare_end,f.fare FROM calendar c
   JOIN vehicles v
   LEFT
   JOIN fares f
     ON f.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id
    AND c.dt BETWEEN f.fare_start AND f.fare_end
  WHERE c.dt BETWEEN '2013-01-20' AND '2013-01-28';
+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| dt         | vehicle_id | fare_start | fare_end   | fare   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| 2013-01-20 | BAL2018    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-20 | BAL2019    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-20 | BAL2020    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-21 | BAL2018    | 2013-01-21 | 2013-01-26 | 555.00 |
| 2013-01-21 | BAL2019    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-21 | BAL2020    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-22 | BAL2018    | 2013-01-21 | 2013-01-26 | 555.00 |
| 2013-01-22 | BAL2019    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-22 | BAL2020    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-23 | BAL2018    | 2013-01-21 | 2013-01-26 | 555.00 |
| 2013-01-23 | BAL2019    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-23 | BAL2020    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-24 | BAL2018    | 2013-01-21 | 2013-01-26 | 555.00 |
| 2013-01-24 | BAL2019    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-24 | BAL2020    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-25 | BAL2018    | 2013-01-21 | 2013-01-26 | 555.00 |
| 2013-01-25 | BAL2019    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-25 | BAL2020    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-26 | BAL2018    | 2013-01-21 | 2013-01-26 | 555.00 |
| 2013-01-26 | BAL2019    | 2013-01-26 | 2013-01-27 | 211.00 |
| 2013-01-26 | BAL2020    | 2013-01-26 | 2013-01-27 | 545.00 |
| 2013-01-27 | BAL2018    | 2013-01-27 | 2013-01-28 | 111.00 |
| 2013-01-27 | BAL2019    | 2013-01-26 | 2013-01-27 | 211.00 |
| 2013-01-27 | BAL2020    | 2013-01-26 | 2013-01-27 | 545.00 |
| 2013-01-28 | BAL2018    | 2013-01-27 | 2013-01-28 | 111.00 |
| 2013-01-28 | BAL2019    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
| 2013-01-28 | BAL2020    | NULL       | NULL       |   NULL |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

27 rows in set (0.00 sec)